# How can we correlate date/time in loadrunner

Tags: timestamp, loadrunner

I am using hp load runner 12.53 version I am getting time stamp like 2017-09-0511:00:44.1017301 in request body

Can any one explain what 1017301 refers to

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the ten millionths of a second:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#fffffffSpecifier

```
The "fffffff" custom format specifier represents the seven most significant 
digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the ten millionths of 
a second in a date and time value.
Although it is possible to display the ten millionths of a second component 
of a time value, that value may not be meaningful. The precision of date and 
time values depends on the resolution of the system clock. On the Windows NT 
3.5 (and later) and Windows Vista operating systems, the clock's resolution 
is approximately 10-15 milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to 13 digits of precision, thousands of a second, quite readily.   For the additional four digits you may as well use a random four digit number with leading zeros.  Your developer is using this to ensure some degree of uniqueness between requests.  If they were really interested in an audit trail on requests then they would use the same clock for the audit collection, which would be the clock at the server, rather than the clock at the client locations, which are all going to be slightly different at the millisecond level even when synced to the same trusted time source.

At the millionths of a second there would be zero opportunity for being similar.

Technically this is not a correlation, which would be a collection of data sent back from a server and placed in a subsequent request.   This is most likely a user assigned parameter where the parameterization engine date functions plus a random number parameter for the remaining four digits can address your need.